# Can I use statsmodel ARIMA to interpolate a time series?

Tags: python, pandas, arima

In Python 3.7, I have a time series represented by a Pandas dataframe in which the index is a DateTimeIndex and the single value column is stock price:

[image]

The gaps correspond to NaN "price" values, and there are 126 non-NaN values and 20 NaN values.  What I'm trying to do is to interpolate the non-NaN values to predict the values that are NaN.  I tried several interpolation methods (linear, cubic spline) but they're not sufficiently accurate, and looking at the plot above, it appears there is a significant upward trend and also some traces of weekly periodicity, so I decided to use statsmodel ARIMA.  Here is my code:

```
def fill_in_dataframe_ARIMA(  df ):
    price_is_not_NaN = df[ 'price' ].notnull()
    price_is_NaN = np.logical_not( price_is_not_NaN )
    # Convert the datetimes of the index into milliseconds:
    datetime_ms = df.index.map( to_ms )
    # Train the ARIMA model:
    train_datetime_ms = datetime_ms[ price_is_not_NaN ]
    train_price = df.price[ price_is_not_NaN ]
    arima_model = ARIMA( train_price, ( 5, 1, 2 ), train_datetime_ms ).fit()
    # Use model to predict the missing prices:
    missing_datetime_ms = datetime_ms[ price_is_NaN ]
    missing_price = arima_model.predict( exog = missing_datetime_ms )
    return missing_price
```

What I'm expecting is that `missing_price` ends up being an array-like object of twenty entries, like `missing_datetime_ms`.  Instead, `missing_price` has 125 entries, one fewer than the number of samples in `train_datetime_ms:train_price`.

Clearly I am not understanding what's meant by *endogenous* and *exogenous* (not to mention *interpolate* vs. *extrapolate*).  Can someone please explain how I can get the intended result of 20 predicted entries?

Comment: I have a similar problem with some air pollution data. Haven't found the solution yet. Have you fixed it?

Comment: I gave up on ARIMA after reading several descriptions that indicated that time series used to train ARIMA must be periodic, and there have to be samples for every period preceding what you want to predict for.   Also, if you decide to try it anyway, check out SARIMA (seasonal ARIMA), which includes handling of seasonality and trend, whereas plain ARIMA assumes the time series is stationary.